# Standard Deviation (SD) for Geometric Mean

Tags: usage-statistics

I want to calculate the Standard Deviation around the Geometric mean for a highly variable data with >500 entries. 
I calculated the geometric mean using the function exp(mean(log(x)))

To calculate the Standard Deviation around the geometric mean I created another function:

function(x) sqrt((sum(((x-(exp(mean(log(x)))))^2))/(NROW(x)-1)))

But applying this gave the following error:

> Error in x : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can anyone help me for calculating the SD around geometric mean by creating a function using logarithms, so that it is arithmetically applicable in a large and varied dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is a php function ( stats_standard_deviation ) that calculate the standard deviation:

See the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-standard-deviation.php)

Example:

> $data = array(2,3,3,3,3,2,5);
>
> $standardDeviation = stats_standard_deviation($data);